# Hibernate Criteria distinct field sorted by date in Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

From the below table, I want to get all records but only a single record of any 'type', with that record being the most recent 'created_at' of that type.

Here's my example table, with distinct being applied to 'type':

`id | name | type | created_at
1  | foo  | 1    | 2016-10-01 
2  | bar  | 2    | 2016-10-02
3  | baz  | 2    | 2016-10-03`

I want the results to be rows 1 and 3, 3 instead of 2 because it's the latest created_at of type 2.

I've tried the line below, but it only gives me an array of distinct types and not the entire record.

`Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(Product.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("type"))).addOrder(Order.desc("createdAt"));`